# How transform results of caml query to rows into columns

Tags: reporting-services

Can anyone tell me how to transform results of caml query to rows into columns.

Caml query is returning results from sharepoint list in the below format.

Column1 Column2 Column3

---

Value 1  Value 2 Value3

But I need the result in the below format

Column    Value

---

Column1   Value1
Column2   Value2
Column3   Value3

Answer (score 0):

You con store the results in a DataTable using [SPListItemCollection.GetDataTable method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemcollection.getdatatable.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Sample from MSDN:

```
SPWeb oWebsite = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPList oList = oWebsite.Lists["List_Name"];
SPListItemCollection collListItems = oList.Items;

DataGrid1.DataSource = collListItems.GetDataTable();
DataGrid1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Actually I am trying to do it with SSRS and I am trying to convert rows into columns..